# How to create UICollectioview Cell Dynamic size like hooked app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm currently working on app in which i need dynamic cell size for UICollectionview similar to `hooked story app`.[image: Dynamic Cell]

Above image show what i need.I tried with other custom libraries such as
`WaterfallCollectionView`,`MosaicLayout`,`FMMosaicLayout`,`greedo-layout`

Using Collectionview Delegate method

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return [self sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

-(CGSize )sizeForPhotoAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
}
```

But my photos load from API so I can't predict size for that cell before image loaded.
So please help me with this.Thank you in Advance.

Comment: I don't really see where your image is actually in your code

Comment: Check Now i added Code for image

Comment: you are getting images from server i think not loading from there, probably this depends on `imageViews` mode `Aspect fit` ect.

Comment: One question, are the images being fit into the UIImageview that have a fixed aspect ratio? Or are you generating them automatically based on the size of the image?

Comment: i'm fitting image in fixed aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track about image at index path is downloaded or not. If its downloaded then return the downloaded image size else return some static image height or simply return `CGSizeZero`. Don't forget to reload cell when image gets downloaded. This all i can suggest with what information you have provided.